# Magento Error: Warning: simplexml_load_string() Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Config.php on line 511

Tags: xml, magento

I have been trying to solve this error message for days now.

Have Added a debugging code and the xml in question is

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <quickview translate="title" module="cmsmquickview">
                                        <title>Quick View Settings</title>
                                        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                                    </quickview>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Please can someone guide me on how to identify whats wrong with this code because the xml seems valid to me.

Thanks

This is all i could see in the var log folder

```
2014-09-01T14:21:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 26: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 511
2014-09-01T14:21:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: --&gt;  in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 511
2014-09-01T14:21:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:    ^  in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 511
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is `[code]` part of your file or the question?  Does the real file actually start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`?

Comment: It is part of the question. I have not checked the  file yet because i have not been able to find it. I am new to Magento, this is my first project so any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "quickview" is not part of standard Magento, it must be an extension.  You can probably uninstall it from the Connect Manager, visit `www.your-site.com/downloader/`.  Alternatively look for related errors in the directories `var/log/` and `var/reports/`.  Also [turn on error reporting](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/).  When you find a clue please update your question with it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you help so far, I have checked the system cant find any module to do with "quickview".. i have updated the post as well.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally,Managed to solve the problem after many hours of debugging.

I checked the xml file once again and saw that the error has to do with this module cmsmquickview, but i don't have any module by that name on my system, so what i did was to check all the module that has to do with cms mart. Right in one of the folders i found this code that absolutely has nothing to do with any module.

Deleted the file and the problem is solved. Hope this help someone in future.

Thanks Guys